# Zooming StateT with return value in indexed container

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm having trouble figuring out the cleanest way of zooming an effect like StateT that returns a value into an indexed container like a vector or a map.

For example let's say I have some structures for a card game:

```
data Card = Card
    { cardValue :: Int
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
makeFields ''Card

data Player = Player
    { playerCards :: [Card]
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
makeFields ''Player

data Game = Game
    { gamePlayers :: M.Map Int Player
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
makeFields ''Game

data Action = GiveCard Card | DoNothing
```

And a function that handles a player's move in a turn with a StateT effect:

```
playerAction :: (MonadIO m) => StateT Player m Action
playerAction = do
    cards' <- use cards
    case cards' of
        (c:rest) -> GiveCard c <$ (cards .= rest)
        _        -> return DoNothing
```

What I want to do is to index inside a player in the game and apply this StateT to that player. Something that looks like this:

```
gameAction :: (MonadIO m) => Int -> StateT Game m ()
gameAction i = do
    Just action <- zoom (players . at i . mapJust) playerAction
    case action of
        GiveCard c -> liftIO $ print c
        DoNothing  -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Doing nothing"
```

Adding `_Just` in the traversal or replacing `at i` with `ix i` results in this compile error:

```
    • Could not deduce (Monoid Action) arising from a use of ‘_Just’
      from the context: MonadIO m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   gameAction :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                                 MonadIO m =>
                                 Int -> StateT Game m ()
        at src/MainModule.hs:36:1-52
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_Just’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘at i . _Just’
      In the first argument of ‘zoom’, namely ‘(players . at i . _Just)’
   |
38 |     action <- zoom (players . at i . _Just) playerAction
   |                                      ^^^^^
```

I could use `non` with a dummy Player value but if the index doesn't exist then it silently runs the function on the dummy value which is not what I want:

```
emptyPlayer :: Player
emptyPlayer = Player []

gameAction :: (MonadIO m) => Int -> StateT Game m ()
gameAction i = do
    action <- zoom (players . at i . non emptyPlayer) playerAction
    case action of
        GiveCard c -> liftIO $ print c
        DoNothing  -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Doing nothing"
```

I could grab the player out with `preuse`, modify it and set the modified value. Calling the function that does this is pretty verbose since it has to take in the runMonad function and the getter and setter lenses.

```
prezoom run get set m = do
    maybeS <- preuse get
    case maybeS of
        Just s -> do
            (r, s') <- lift $ run m s
            set .= s'
            return $ Just r
        Nothing -> return Nothing

gameAction :: (MonadIO m) => Int -> StateT Game m ()
gameAction i = do
    Just action <- prezoom runStateT (players . ix i) (players . ix i) playerAction
    case action of
        GiveCard c -> liftIO $ print c
        DoNothing  -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Doing nothing"
```

I don't really like the above ways of zooming into an indexed container. Is there an easier and cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a handle on what the underlying semantic issue is, but let me restate it for clarity.

`at i` is a `Lens` into a container which returns a `Maybe`, because the item may be missing from the container (perhaps the index is beyond the end of the list). Composing such a `Lens` with a `Prism` like `_Just` turns the whole thing into a `Traversal`:

```
players . at i . _Just :: Traversal' Game Player
```

Now, `zoom` does work with `Traversal`s, but it needs a `Monoid` for the return value of the stateful action. From [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom):

> When applied to a `Traversal'` over multiple values, the actions for each target are executed sequentially and the results are aggregated.

A `Traversal` may return zero-or-many results, so `zoom` will execute the monadic action zero-or-many times, filling in `mempty` as a default value and combining multiple results with `mappend`. The docs also feature the following specialised type signature for `zoom`, which demonstrates the `Monoid` constraint:

```
zoom :: (Monad m, Monoid c) => Traversal' s t -> StateT t m c -> StateT s m c
```

That’s why your error message says “Could not deduce `(Monoid Action)`”: `playerAction` returns an `Action` and `zoom` needs a `Monoid` for `Action` because you handed it a `Traversal`.

So the fix is to pick a `Monoid` to return from the stateful action. We know that the `Traversal` will either hit one or zero targets - `at i` never returns multiple results - so the correct semantics for the `Monoid` we’re looking for are “first-result-or-failure”.  That `Monoid` is [`First`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First). (We don’t need to worry about throwing away extra results because there won’t be any.)

```
action <- getFirst <$> zoom (players . at i . _Just) (fmap (First . Just) playerAction)
-- here action :: Maybe Action
```

(I’m on my phone so I haven’t tested this code!) You might be able to clean this up a bit using `ala`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want it to do? Crash? `zoom (players . singular (ix i))` will do that.